# Can't make samba share writable

Tags: debian, samba, smbclient

I'm trying to make my samba share (running on Debian 10) writable but it seems that anything I try just breaks the share and I cannot access it anymore.

Here's my current configuration:

```
[MediaServer4TB]
   comment = Media Server 4TB
   browseable = yes
   path = /media/sf_filesrvr
   guest ok = no
   read only = no
   create mask = 0600
   directory mask = 0700
   security = user
   encrypt passwords = yes
   force user = root
   writeable = yes
```

The client is an Ubuntu 20.04 LTS machine.

Could the issue be that the machine is a virtual machine using a virtual folder as directory for the share? If yes, how would you proceed?

**EDIT: I realized I can copy files and folders from the remote machine but I cannot move files inside the samba share. The directory `/media/sf_filesrvr` is writable by root (the user that is trying to access it)**

Here is the log output for the specific client:

```
[2022/05/01 15:33:49.864251,  3] ../../auth/ntlmssp/ntlmssp_sign.c:623(ntlmssp_sign_reset)
  NTLMSSP Sign/Seal - Initialising with flags:
[2022/05/01 15:33:49.864280,  3] ../../auth/ntlmssp/ntlmssp_util.c:72(debug_ntlmssp_flags)
  Got NTLMSSP neg_flags=0x62088215
[2022/05/01 15:33:49.864331,  3] ../../auth/ntlmssp/ntlmssp_sign.c:623(ntlmssp_sign_reset)
  NTLMSSP Sign/Seal - Initialising with flags:
[2022/05/01 15:33:49.864352,  3] ../../auth/ntlmssp/ntlmssp_util.c:72(debug_ntlmssp_flags)
  Got NTLMSSP neg_flags=0x62088215
[2022/05/01 15:33:49.864612,  3] ../../source3/auth/token_util.c:688(finalize_local_nt_token)
  Failed to fetch domain sid for WORKGROUP
[2022/05/01 15:33:49.865078,  3] ../../source3/groupdb/mapping.c:854(pdb_create_builtin_alias)
  pdb_create_builtin_alias: Could not get a gid out of winbind
[2022/05/01 15:33:49.865115,  2] ../../source3/auth/token_util.c:719(finalize_local_nt_token)
  WARNING: Failed to create BUILTIN\Administrators group!  Can Winbind allocate gids?
[2022/05/01 15:33:49.865611,  3] ../../source3/groupdb/mapping.c:854(pdb_create_builtin_alias)
  pdb_create_builtin_alias: Could not get a gid out of winbind
[2022/05/01 15:33:49.865647,  2] ../../source3/auth/token_util.c:739(finalize_local_nt_token)
  WARNING: Failed to create BUILTIN\Users group! Can Winbind allocate gids?
[2022/05/01 15:33:49.866176,  3] ../../source3/groupdb/mapping.c:854(pdb_create_builtin_alias)
  pdb_create_builtin_alias: Could not get a gid out of winbind
[2022/05/01 15:33:50.008196,  3] ../../source3/smbd/password.c:84(register_homes_share)
  Adding homes service for user 'root' using home directory: '/root'
```

Comment: Is the directory `/media/sf_filesrvr` writable by the user who is trying to write to it? What do the logs say? Add this information to the question. Do not post it in the comments.

Comment: Addded the information in the question.

Comment: `security = user` is a global setting and cannot be in the share definition. (See `man smb.conf` and notice that the definition has `(G)` after it rather than `(S)`, showing it much be in the global section

Answer (score 0):

This awnser solves the problem in case you can mount your share properly with an user/passwd pair and you are able to read the content of the share from a remote client, but you can't write into the share.

Of course you need a section in your `/etc/samba/smb.conf` like this:

```
[BobsVolume]
comment = BobsVolume
path = /mnt/BobsVolume
create mask = 0600
directory mask = 0700
read only=No
guest ok=No
valid users = bob
```

The most important parameter is `read only=no` and `valid user`. `writeable=yes` is a synonym.

Well, it seems to me that nobody's answer across internet contains the key to solve the problem and that is: **your share must be owned by your system's `smbuser:smbgroup`**.

If you are using the docker image `dperson/samba`, dont forget to run

```
chown smbuser:smb /mnt/BobsVolume
```

in this example.

Comment: The OP had `force user = root` so local filesystem permissions shouldn't have been an issue